# add normal text type field (not text box) to form in symfony

Tags: symfony

I want to show a list of names (which I get from a database) in a form with its corresponding delete and update button. But by adding a field to the form like this:`->add('nombre',null,array('data' => $gen["name"],'label' =>'nombre', 'attr' => array('class' => 'className')))`
It appears to me as a text box and what I want is the text, I do not know if I explain myself, not as a textbox. I want it like this: https://postimg.cc/2LWQhMDM
This is the code of my controller:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use AppBundle\Entity\Genus;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use AppBundle\Form\GenusFormType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\AddressType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\HiddenType;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @Route("/", name="homepage"))
 */

public function newAction(Request $request)
{
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$genuses = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Genus')
->consulta(20);

foreach ($genuses as $gen)
{
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
//->setAction($this->generateUrl('app_lucky_number'))
->setAction($this->generateUrl('homepage'))
->setMethod ("POST")
->add('nombre',null,array('data' => $gen["name"],'label' =>'nombre', 'attr' =>   array('class' => 'className')))
->add('id',HiddenType::class, ['data' => $gen["id"],])
->add('actualizar', SubmitType::class,array('label' => 'actualizar','attr' => array('class' => 'className')))
->add('borrar', SubmitType::class,array('label' => 'borrar','attr' => array('class' => 'className')))        
->getForm();
$form->handleRequest($request);
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $genus = $form->getData();
    $id=$genus["id"];
    if ($form->get('borrar')->isClicked())
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $genuses = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Genus')
        ->borrar($id);
    }
   
    //return $this->render('genus/principal.html.twig',array('name'=>$name));
    return $this->render('genus/principal.html.twig',array('id'=>$id));
}
$formularios[]=$form->createView();
}        
return $this->render('genus/show.html.twig',['genuses'=>$formularios]);
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the better solution would be to create separate update and delete methods in the controller.

So u can build a tabel as showen in your screenshop by giveing the data of $genuses to the template show.html.twig .

And there u make an a-tag like:

```
<a href="{{ path('app_route_to_metho_delete', {id: genuses.id}) }}">Delete</a>
```

Comment: I don't need to put the data in the table, I just need to put the text without being a textbox

Comment: i've founded this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34856109/symfony-add-text-in-generated-form  It saids that for adding plain text to a form it can only be done in the template.

Comment: Yes. Right, but u dont need to change the form. 
Just put the data to the template and fill in where ever u want.
Controler:
return $this->render('template.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'data' => $data
        ]);
Template:
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{data}}
{{ form_widget(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}